# List of figures, list of tables, and section numbers after 1 digit gets into text

Tags: table-of-contents

My tables and list of figures and section & subsection ordering numbers get into the text. I have attached the list of figures where this problem is occurring. Can someone help in solving this problem?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I am using amsbook as my document class.